# What does the (+) plus symbol in date command refer to?

Tags: linux, bash

For example the following command `$ date "+%D"` outputs MM/DD/YY. What does the `+` do or refer to? It is not in the man pages.

Comment: Which man page are you referring to?

Comment: This is not a "linux command". The OS is probably Gnu/Linux. The `+` is interpreted by the command (`date`) in this case. The `$` is not part of the command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s shown in the [`date` man page’s synopsis](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html#SYNOPSIS):

`date [OPTION]... [+FORMAT]`

Its purpose, when used with `date`, is to indicate that the string following it specifies the output format.

It has different meanings in different contexts; see your shell’s documentation and specific man pages for details.

Comment: Note that this meaning is specific to the `date` command; some other commands use it to mean completely different things (or nothing), and it has some non-command-related functions that're different as well (e.g. `${var+string}` expands to "string" if a variable named `var` is set, or nothing if there's no variable by that name).